# looking for documentation about exploiiting OSM file with c++ API

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, api, c++

My application is written in QT4.6, i use the C++ API of QGIS 2.8.2
i had to read and display OpenStreetMap in my canvas in my application
so, i am looking for some documentation or tutorial for reading, exploring, exploiting or coding the OSM file
i must not use the QGIS application, i have a specific application for a project, and the project had to read and display OSM File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two OSM aware programs that I know are based on Qt framework:
Merkaartor and Marble, both are opensource.

And OSM frameworks based on C++ are listed in the OSM wiki at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks